# Odin beta screen freezes on boot but computer still working after installing NVIDIA drivers

Tags: nvidia

I tried installing Odin Beta today and it went smoothly. With the default nouveau drivers it works fine, albeit a tad slow during animations.

Then I proceeded to install `nvidia-drivers-460`. The installation completed alright but after a restart, on the logon screen, it freezes. The thing is, it still running, it's just the image that froze. If I type in my password nothing changes on screen but the login happens. I can switch tty with CTRL+ALT+F1, for instance, and reboot but all the while the image on display stays the same.

I'm using a 3060 Ti. I was using the Juno with the NVIDIA drivers just fine, including the 460 one.

Comment: I say it worked fined in reality I lose display image when I wake the computer up. Similar deal though, it still working, it's just the display that never wakes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! I now have NVIDIA 460 drivers working perfectly on Odin beta 1.

What I did was:

1. Installed kernel headers with:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   ```
2. Installed nvidia drivers with:

   ```
   sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-460
   ```
3. Recreated grub config (thanks for the tip u/Ashtefere)

   ```
   sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub/grub.cfg
   ```